# coffee script identation

Tags: javascript, asp.net, coffeescript

I get an identation error for these lines

Is there any online validator that can help me?

```
showAliveTests : (pageIndex, statusFilter) ->
    data=
            pageIndex:pageIndex
            status:statusFilter
        $.ajax 
            url:'/ManageConfiguration/GetAliveConfigurations/' + location.search
            type:"post"
            data:data
            dataType:"json"
            success:(res)->
                if res.status == "failed"
                    alert res.body
                else
                    $('#viewConfigurationTable tr').remove()
                    newRow =    $ '<tr>'
                    newRow.append('<td>Id</td>
                                    <td>Name</td>
                                    <td>Status</td>
                                    <td>Ctids</td>
                                    <td>CreationDate</td>')
                    $('#viewConfigurationTable').append(newRow)
                    for obj in res.body
                        newRow =    $ '<tr>'
                        newRow.append('<td>'+obj.Id+'</td> 
                                        <td>'+obj.Name+'</td>
                                        <td>'+obj.Status+'</td>
                                        <td>'+obj.Ctids+'</td>
                                        <td>'+obj.CreationDate+'</td>')
                    $('#viewConfigurationTable').append(newRow) 
                    $(#paginator a).remove()
                    for i in [0..count] by 1
                        $(#paginator).append('<a href=#>'+i+'</a>') 

            error:(e)->
                alert 'An error has occured: ' + e
```

Comment: Where exactly is the error? Does your compiler give any indication?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

www.coffeescript.org -> click try me, paste your code inside and you will see which line throws the error.

in your case you can see it even with stackoverflow code highlighting:

```
$(#paginator a).remove() -> wrong
$('#paginator a').remove() -> correct
```

second error

```
$(#paginator).append('<a href=#>'+i+'</a>')  -> wrong
$('#paginator').append('<a href=#>'+i+'</a>')  -> correct
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the quotes around `#paginator a` and `paginator`

```
#...
$("#paginator a").remove() # you had: $(#paginator a)
for i in [0..count] by 1
    $("#paginator").append('<a href=#>'+i+'</a>') # you had: $(#paginator)
#...
```